# Laravel based package custom error pages

Tags: php, laravel

In the spirit of keeping a developer's hands as much as possible out of the core installation of laravel, I am trying to find a way to use custom error pages without messing with the core resources folder's blade files, but use the ones provided from the package relevant folder. 
So is there a way to include error page templates in the ServiceProvider like with the `$this->loadViewsFrom`?

Answer (score 1):

in the `resources/views` folder you'll find a folder called `errors`. In here you can create custom error pages.

For example:
**404.blade.php**

```
<html>
  <head><title>Page not found :o</title></head>
  <body>
    <h1>Sorry, we can't find what you're looking for.</h1>
    <a href="https://example.com">Take me back to the main site.</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

This page will now show automagically when your application throws a 404. (you can do this with all http response codes)

Comment: hello Jesse, thanks for your reply mate but this is not what I'm looking for. I probably haven't phrased my question very well but what you are suggesting is what I don't want to use. You see I work with a single installation of laravel and have each of my projects organized in a package folder and I want everything to be in there. Thanks again for your reply.